# How to scale airfoil coordinates to achieve the required size?

Tags: aerospace-engineering, aerodynamics, airfoils

I'm using airfoil data that is generated by a program. The generated airfoil has a chord length of 1 unit. I want to know how to scale up this airfoil to required chord length. My airfoil series number 638xx. NACA five digit series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple math question. Multiply your x and y coordinates by the scaling factor you want. Say your chord length is 100mm. To make it 150mm, multiply all your values by 1.5. If you have a picture of an airfoil, just scale the image by 150%.

Comment: What about the y coordinates ?

Comment: Multiply both x any x values by your scaling factor.

Comment: Did that do the trick?

Comment: No, I was a following a video tutorial done by some guy on youtube. He shared his airfoil section coordinate files. When I check the scaling factor for the airfoil coordinates, it is different for x and y coordinates. For reference I'm adding pastebin [link](http://pastebin.com/4gybQCfV)  and the original coordinates [data](http://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord/naca4415.dat)

Comment: he is using NACA 4415

Comment: I thought the scaling factor would be same like you. But this is showing its different for x and y coordinates.

Comment: That's interesting. If you scale both values differently you are going to get a different airfoil aren't you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54508/discussion-between-papabiceps-and-mountainclimberi).

Answer (score 2):

MountainClimberi is correct. Multiplying both x and y coordinates by the same factor will scale your airfoil correctly. Using a different factor for each will result in a different aspect ratio and a different(stretched) version of that airfoil that will not match its published properties.

Also remember that after scaling the data, your reference location will have moved if it was not (0,0). This may require a translation operation if you need to adjust it.

Per [Scaling(geometry) wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_(geometry)): "The scaling is uniform if and only if the scaling factors are equal (vx = vy = vz)"

Willamate.edu has a good article on [2D transformations](https://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/GeneralGraphics/Transforms/transforms2d.htm) including scaling.

Python would be a good language to manipulate this data with. Here is an [SE python scaling question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450035/scale-2d-coordinates-and-keep-their-relative-euclidean-distances-intact).